# Postgresql: Query is not returning data, updated in fiddle

Tags: postgresql

I have one query here in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/96UZ2bH7jM5QcoDkDZCacX/0), I want to get the orders with order_items and order_combo_items which is specifically from one category, that works.

But here in this [scenario](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rg68W9xEYJPXK1QvoK4j9r/0) which is not working. Any idea about this query?

Thank

Comment: Though it's good, to create a fiddle, your code should also be in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, as you are doing an inner join, only records contained in both tables will be selected.Try doing a right join instead of inner join to get the required data

```
SELECT * FROM orders RIGHT JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id AND order_items.category_id IN (123)LEFT JOIN order_combo_items ON order_combo_items.order_id = orders.id AND order_combo_items.category_id IN (123);
```

Comment: But that will give null values